# Using Google Maps: a custom javascript function returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return the variable `coord` from GetLocation, but it only returns undefined.
Any help appreciated!

```
var coord = "";
function GetLocation(address) {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode( { "address": address }, function (results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            coord = ParseLocation(results[0].geometry.location);

            // This alert shows the proper coordinates 
            alert(coord);
        }
        else{ }

    });

    // this alert is undefined
    alert(coord);
    return coord;
}

function ParseLocation(location) {

    var lat = location.lat().toString().substr(0, 12);
    var lng = location.lng().toString().substr(0, 12);

    return lat+","+lng;
}
```

Comment: Does `geocode()` execute asynchronously? If so, `coord` value is not yet know at the time the function returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are returning `coords` from the outer function it is still in fact `undefined`. The inner function executes later when the asynchronous operation (if it wasn't asynchronous, the API would just give the result to you normally) is done.

Try passing a callback:

```
function GetLocation(address, cb) {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode( { "address": address }, function (results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            cb(ParseLocation(results[0].geometry.location));
        }
        else{ }

    });
}
```

You can then use it like so:

```
GetLocation( "asd", function(coord){
    alert(coord);
});
```

Comment: Ultimately I want to return the value from the function. yet if I do something like this `var test = GetLocation( "asd", function(coord){
   return coord;
});`
 I don't think it'll work will it?

Comment: No you cannot do it, this is why it takes a function in the first place. If you could do that, they would just return it normally. Duh, right? :P You cannot get far with javascript if you just treat it as a linear sequence of commands anyway. Events, XHR requests etc are all asynchronous.

Comment: Got it, was just hoping there would be a way around it. Ta!